# how to use custom attributes that a library has?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-library

i added a project library to my project, it has some  custom attributes defined in its `attrs.xml` how can i use these attributes ?

Library code:
attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="NumberProgressBar">
        <attr name="progress" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="max" format="integer"/>

        <attr name="progress_unreached_color" format="color"/>
        <attr name="progress_reached_color" format="color"/>

        <attr name="progress_reached_bar_height" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="progress_unreached_bar_height" format="dimension"/>

        <attr name="progress_text_size" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="progress_text_color" format="color"/>

        <attr name="progress_text_offset" format="dimension"/>

        <attr name="progress_text_visibility" format="enum">
            <enum name="visible" value="0"/>
            <enum name="invisible" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="Themes">
        <attr name="numberProgressBarStyle" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:widget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lessens_listview_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bbb"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="26dp" />

           <com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar
               android:id="@+id/number_progress_bar"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lessens_listview_textview"
               android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                custom:progress_reached_bar_height="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

here i get error in `custom:progress_reached_bar_height="5dp"`

as the library's Readme says i can use attributes like this but i cant.

library Readme:

```
<com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        custom:progress_unreached_color="#CCCCCC"
        custom:progress_reached_color="#3498DB"

        custom:progress_unreached_bar_height="0.75dp"
        custom:progress_reached_bar_height="1.5dp"

        custom:progress_text_size="10sp"
        custom:progress_text_color="#3498DB"
        custom:progress_text_offset="1dp"
        custom:progress_text_visibility="visible"

        custom:max="100"
        custom:progress="80"
         />
```

Comment: Your top level view needs to include a line like this: `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourpackagename"`.

Comment: The answer below is a better solution if you use Gradle with multiple package names.

Comment: can i use in eclipse?

Comment: Yeah, I think it works in both so you might as well use the below (`res-auto`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how you declare the namespace.
In your case you have declared:

```
xmlns:widget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

that means you can call the attributes using `widget` as prefix:

```
widget:progress_reached_bar_height="5dp"
```

If you want to use the `custom` prefix change the declaration in this way:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```